# Fetch the value of dynamically created textbox

Tags: javascript, dynamic, textbox

I want to fetch the dynamically created textbox values. 
My js code is,

```js
$('#Dynm_Device_Fields').append('<div class="col-sm-12 form-group"><div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></div></div>');

$(document).on('click','.add',function(){
        inner_div = "";
        id_cnt = id_cnt + 1;
        inner_div = "<div class='col-sm-12 form-group'><label class='col-sm-4 control-label'></label><div class='col-sm-7'><div class='col-sm-4'><input name = 'Dynm_Key_"+id_cnt+"' id='Dynm_Key_"+id_cnt+"' type='text'  class='form-control adcol' placeholder='Field Name' /></div><div class='col-sm-4'><input name = 'Dynm_Val_"+id_cnt+"' id='Dynm_Val_"+id_cnt+"' type='text' class='form-control adcol' placeholder='Field Value' /></div></div><button name = 'DynmButtonBox' type='button' style='width:35px;' class='btn btn-danger remove col-sm-1 fa fa-close' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' data-original-title='Remove' ></button><br></div>";
        $('#Dynm_Device_Fields').append(inner_div);
});
```

Please help to find out the solution.
Thanks

Comment: where is textbox ?

Comment: Please look into the inner_div part @GeorgeBailey

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.adcol', function() {
  $(this).val()
});`

Comment: let me know if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbox I am seeing is:

```
<input name='Dynm_Val_"+id_cnt+"' 
    id='Dynm_Val_"+id_cnt+"' 
    type='text' 
    class='form-control adcol' 
    placeholder='Field Value' />
```

Using JQuery:

```
var val = $('#Dynm_Val_' + id_cnt).val();
```

If you need to get an array of all the text boxes:

```
var textboxElements = $('input.adcol');
```

Or plain JavaScript, try:

```
var val = document.getElementById('Dynm_Val_' + id_cnt).value; // single
var textboxElements = document.querySelectorAll('input.adcol'); // array of elements
```

Comment: Thanks for above solution. But when I print the array of element then it gives me 'undefined'.

Comment: @Prafulla, I modified the selector for the class, maybe that will help, also how are you printing the array of elements?

Comment: var textboxElements = $('input.adcol'); alert(JSON.stringify(textboxElements); - I use this code to print. But gives me something else output.

Comment: @Prafulla, textboxElements is an array of elements, iterate it in a for loop and use **.val()** (or **.value**) on each individual element to print the value each textbox

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you have `.addcol` on dynamically added textboxes. Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.adcol', function() { alert($(this).val()) });
```